# odata java service unable to call in c# code using Rest sharp

Tags: java, c#, rest, odata, asp.net-web-api

MYDEMOCLASS.CS

```
 public class MYDEMOCLASS 
    {
      private string title;
      private string myid;
     private IDictionary<string, pocClass> _demo;
     
      private long _Id;
      
          public virtual long Id
        {
            get
            {
                return _Id;
            }
            set
            {
                this._Id = value;
            }
        }
        
  public virtual IDictionary<string, pocClass> demo
        {
            get
            {
                return demo;
            }
            set
            {
                this._demo = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

c# code

```
var demoObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MYClassObject);
  // demoObject value is {"myId":111}
var restClient = new RestClient("http://myservice/");

RestSharp.IRestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest("rest/", Method.POST) { RequestFormat = RestSharp.DataFormat.Json }
.AddBody(demoObject);
// easily add HTTP Headers
restRequest.AddHeader("header", "value");
// execute the request
RestSharp.IRestResponse restResponse = restClient.Execute<MYDEMOCLASS>(restRequest);
```

While accessing rest service ,I'm getting this exception:

> {"errorCode":"500","message":"Could not read JSON:  Can not
> instantiate value of type [simple type, class MYDEMOCLASS] from String
> value;
>
> no single-String constructor/factory method; nested exception is
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:  Can not
> instantiate value of type [simple type, class MYDEMOCLASS] from String
> value;  no single-String constructor/factory method",
>
> "innerError":{"trace":[{"methodName":"readJavaType","fileName":"MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java","lineNumber":171,"className":"org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter","nativeMethod":false},

Any clue why?

> I have converted MyDemoClass code from java class to c#. service i'm
> exposing is of Java, but my above code is using c# may be because of
> this i'm getting convertion type issue , give me any clue thanks

Comment: have you defined the MYDEMOCLASS in your code. Include a snippet of it would be the first step towards making this question complete. Also have you ensured that the http://myservice/ is accessible on your browser. The error code **500** roughly is **SERVER INTERNAL** _HTTP_ Error

Comment: "header" and "value" are placeholders, aren't they? You need to add an actual http header such as Content-Encoding and assign a value to it if this is required by your web application, or just omit the `restRequest.AddHeader("header", "value");`
line altogether from your code.

Comment: updated MyDemoClass.cs also , actually I have converted this class from java to c# service i'm exposing is of Java, but my above code is using c# may be because of this i'm getting convertion type issue , give me any clue thanks